# to find willing ears

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

What does 'to find willing ears' mean in the following context ?

> Moreover, these advances in thought coincided with anti-church and
>   government sentiment that was already growing among European
>   commoners. The Catholic Church at the time was famously corrupt, and
>   it often ruled using intimidation, fear, and false knowledge and was
>   violently intolerant toward dissenters and heretics. Subsequently,
>   when Enlightenment philosophers came along praising liberty and
>   self-empowerment, they **found willing ears**.

http://www.sparknotes.com/history/european/enlightenment/section1/page/2/

Comment: It means they found people who were willing to consider and listen to their ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Willing ears' is an idiom meaning 'people who are receptive [to the ideas presented]'.

The passage is explaining that people were more willing to listen to ideas of liberty and self-empowerment, because of the bad things the Church (which, it is implied, opposed those ideas) had been doing to them.